# Timeout while starting Python application through Cloud Foundry

Tags: python, flask, pip, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am using Cloud Foundry CLI for pushing a flask application on IBM Bluemix.
As soon as I run `cf push <APPNAME>` it creates the buildpack and everything, but it keeps crashing the application while trying to start it.

The error I get is as shown:

```
App instance exited with guid 452bafde-cdaf-4794-8e33-f91802a3e2df payload: 
{"cc_partition"=>"default", 
 "droplet"=>"452bafde-cdaf-4794-8e33-f91802a3e2df", 
 "version"=>"1951c4c4-66e6-4f56-b302-541383014bd2", 
 "instance"=>"a8328f7525f247cd94fdaf23382fac78", 
 "index"=>0, 
 "reason"=>"CRASHED",
 "exit_status"=>-1, 
 "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", 
 "crash_timestamp"=>1454112272}
```

Comment: Are you running this app with `no-route`? Can you provide some more information about your app and its configuration?

Comment: Please add output of 'cf logs appname --recent'. You may need to recreate the problem to get latest logs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and after some looking around found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ihuston/e87c1d4719f7e72e9760) with a sample flask project for cloud foundry.

I noticed that when starting the server the sample sets the host to '0.0.0.0' which was something I was not doing.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, debug=DEBUG)
```

After making the change my application worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to piggyback on drieprinter's answer for a more complete implementation
Put this on the very bottom of the python file

```
import os

port = os.getenv('PORT', '5000')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase timeout by calling `cf push -t 180` or change `health-check-type` inside the **manifest.yml**:

```
---
applications:
- name: ...
  health-check-type: process
```